# How to add additional text to file php

Tags: php, text, fwrite

This is my code:

```
$open = fopen('emails.txt', 'w+');                  
if ($open) {
    $content = "$first $last <$email>,";
    if (fwrite($open, $content)) {
         // ...
     }
}
```

However, when I run this, it just replaces the text I already have in the file. How do I just add to the file, instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open the file in append mode, by passing `a` as the second parameter to `fopen()`:

```
$open = fopen("emails.txt", 'a');
```

Then, data you write to the file will be appended to the end of the file, preserving data that was previously written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only appending one block of text into the file at every request, you could look into [`file_put_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents) as well:

```
file_put_contents('emails.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Shorter than having to write `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`, though the latter is more or less optional :)